# How To Get HTTP Status Codes From Qt QWebEngineView?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I've been looking through the QT docs to find a way to return the http status codes from a QWebEngineView after loading a page, and making a request. I understand that QWebEngineView does not interact with QNetWorkAccessManager which would make this a breeze to accomplish. So is there any other way to get the HTTP status code from a request using QWebEngineView?? I tried multiple ways including RequestInterceptor. Below is a snippet of my attempt using RequestInterceptor, but its not giving me actual HTTP Status codes, just constant values, which is what I dont want.

```
 /*************requestinterceptor.h**************/
#ifndef REQUESTINTERCEPTOR_H
#define REQUESTINTERCEPTOR_H

#include <QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor>
#include <QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QUrl>

class RequestInterceptor : public QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor
{
      public:
      explicit RequestInterceptor(QObject * parent = Q_NULLPTR);
       virtual void interceptRequest(QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo & info) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};
  #endif // REQUESTINTERCEPTOR_H

/*************requestinterceptor.cpp***************/

  #include "requestinterceptor.h"

  RequestInterceptor::RequestInterceptor(QObject * parent)
 :QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(parent){}

 void RequestInterceptor::interceptRequest(QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo & info)
  {
  QString rsrct = "";
 switch(info.resourceType())
  {
      case 1:rsrct="ResourceTypeSubFrame, --> frame or iframe";break;
      case 2:rsrct="ResourceTypeStylesheet, --> a CSS stylesheet";break;
      case 3:rsrct="ResourceTypeScript, --> an external script";break;
      case 4:rsrct="ResourceTypeImage, --> an image (jpg/gif/png/etc)";break;
      case 5:rsrct="ResourceTypeFontResource, --> a font";break;
      case 6:rsrct="ResourceTypeSubResource, --> an other subresource.";break;
      case 7:rsrct="ResourceTypeObject, --> an object (or embed) tag for a plugin,";break;
      case 8:rsrct="ResourceTypeMedia, --> a media resource.";break;
      case 9:rsrct="ResourceTypeWorker, --> the main resource of a dedicated worker.";break;
      case 10:rsrct="ResourceTypeSharedWorker, --> the main resource of a shared worker.";break;
      case 11:rsrct="ResourceTypePrefetch, --> an explicitly requested prefetch";break;
      case 12:rsrct="ResourceTypeFavicon, --> a favicon";break;
      case 13:rsrct="ResourceTypeXhr, --> a XMLHttpRequest";break;
      case 14:rsrct="ResourceTypePing, --> a ping request for <a ping>";break;
      case 15:rsrct="ResourceTypeServiceWorker, --> the main resource of a service worker.";break;
  case 16:rsrct="ResourceTypeUnknown";break;

  default : rsrct="Unknown type";break;
}

qDebug()<<"\t"<<Q_FUNC_INFO<<":\n\t\t" << 
"WebUrlRequestInterceptor::interceptRequest    " <<info.requestMethod()
   <<"\r\n  "<<info.requestUrl()<<"   "<<rsrct      <<"\r\n";
}


  /*************mainwindow.cpp***************/
 const QUrl url("http://google.com");
 view = new WebView();
 view = new QWebEngineView();
 interceptor = new RequestInterceptor(view);
 profile = new QWebEngineProfile(view);
 profile->setRequestInterceptor(interceptor);
 page = new QWebEnginePage(profile,view);
 view->setPage(page);
```

Comment: It seems strange to me but in C ++ it seems that there is no solution since you can check the source code:  http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebengine.git/tree/src/webenginewidgets/api/qwebenginepage.cpp#n367 , 
But on the QML side it is enabled and you can use the signal loadingChanged: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html#loadingChanged-signal that returns a WebEngineLoadRequest that has that information.

Comment: @eyllanesc, just curious, usually the HTTP codes come directly from the server response in the headers of the response. So is there a way to get those response codes from the header in the html source code..???

Comment: If you make the direct request you process it, but in the case of QtWebEngine he sends those requests and he receives them.

Comment: plus: HTML is just part of the answer, the header is not part of the HTML.

Comment: @eyllanesc, thanks.  WebEngine QML looks like something i might have to change to, being that QWebEngine does not give me any http status codes. I hope porting from QTWebEngine  to WebEngine QML is very similar, being that my desktop app is using QTWebEngine.

Answer (score 1):

after hours searching, I found it is impossible to get HTTP status code via QWebEngine at the moment. load completed event doesn't return any status code as well

then I found a solution

```
setting = webpage.settings()
setting.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.ErrorPageEnabled, False)
```

Comment: Could you add some more details buddy?

Comment: After you disable the error page, what do you then need to do to get the HTTP status code?